# Should I use require if I could substitute it for an if statement

Tags: optimization, require

I'm having a hard time defining for myself what would be the best approach for when to use `require` and when to use an `if` statement.

Let's take the following method for sake of example:

```
function setOwner(address _newOwner) public {
    require(_newOwner != address(0), "cannot set owner to 0");
    owner = _newOwner;
}
```

Would it make sense to write such a function like so:

```
function setOwner(address _newOwner) public {
    if (_newOwner != address(0)) {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }
}
```

Is there real advantages and/or detrements to using either? I can see the argument being made that the `require` is way more verbose, and helps the end user of the contract understand whats going wrong. Besides this, I would like to know if there's any implications concerning the performance *(read: gas fees)*.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require will stop the call or revert the transaction, the if statement won't. If you are trying to replace `require` you will have to use `revert`.
So your examples don't serve the same thing and you can't compare them.

to replace `require` you will need to do something like this :

```
function setOwner(address _newOwner) public {
    if (_newOwner == address(0)) {
        revert("cannot set owner to 0")
    }
}
```

and that would make it 2 statements instead of one which would increase the gas cost.

From a functionality perspective, the one of a standard ownership change feature, `setOwner` should be as elementary as possible so putting more conditions and logic in it would make your contract more hard to read and proof and thus harder to trust. It's better to create another feature that uses `_setOwner` a private function that simply does the owner address with the null address check.